# Firebase function configuration reverting back to default databaseurl following deployment

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am attempting to reference a non default real time database from a firebase function.
I notice that performing a deployment via `firebase deploy --only functions` tends to reset the FIREBASE_CONFIG databaseURL property back to the default RTDB.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Initalise a new firebase functions project with http, pubsub, analytics & RTDB features
2. Uncomment the default HTTP function.
3. Deploy the functions (creating the RTDB via the deployment)
4. Create a new RTDB
5. Update the FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable to reference the new RTDB (& re-deploy via the portal)
6. At this point the new RTDB is still correctly referenced
7. Re-deploy the functions via the firebase CLI (firebase deploy --only functions)
8. The FIREBASE_CONFIG databaseUrl property has been reset to point at the default RTDB once more

Is this the expected behaviour?
This does not occur every time.

My HTTP function:

```
export const helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
    logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

I have also attempted to initialise the database via code by following the parameterised configuration approach as described on https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=1st.

```
import {projectID, databaseURL} from "firebase-functions/params";
const firebaseConfig = {
  projectId: projectID.value(),
  databaseURL: databaseURL.value(),
};
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

and also

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Maybe I added this code before the CLI deployment prompted me to create the RTDB.

Do we need to explicitly set the databaseURL property via code to overcome this?
I'd rather not have to hard code any values if it can be avoided.

Is the environment variables approach as described in the documentation a better approach for the given scenario?
When previously attempting this I found that updates to the runtime environment variables were then ignored.

Comment: By hardcoding the databaseURL I am able to ensure that the correct RTDB is updated.

But this indicates that unless you are using the default RTDB, the FIREBASE_CONFIG property should be ignored.